# What is the difference between the words "fariĝi" and "okazi" when meaning "to happen"?

Tags: word-difference

They both can mean "to happen" I'm not sure what the difference is. Please provide a sentence example. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Fariĝi* can be considered a passive form of *to make* or *to do*. I think it would more often be translated by *to become*. For example:

> Mi fariĝis kuracisto – I became a doctor
>
> Lia dorso fariĝis rigida – His back became rigid

You could also translate it with *to be made* or *to be done*. That is probably the source of the confusion because that kind of sentence could also be replaced with *okazi*. However, with *fariĝi* I think there is an emphasis on the fact that something came into being or was created.

> Fariĝis lumo! – Light was made! (like in the bible)
>
> Kiam la suno leviĝas, fariĝas mateno – When the sun rises, it becomes morning

*Okazi* is more about an event taking place in time.

> La Universala Kongreso okazas ĉiu-jare – The UK happens every year
>
> Se la fina venko okazos, estos monda paco – If the final victory (of Esperanto) happens, there will be world peace.